# Include indication of extreme outliers in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, outliers

I have some very, very few outliers in my dataset making the boxplots difficult to read:

```
library(ggplot2)
mtcars$mpg[1] <- 60
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))
p + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Hence, I would like to indicate the extreme outliers like this:

[image]

Any ideas how to do this in `ggplot2`? Transforming the axis is not an option for me...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a start:

```
library("ggplot2")
mtcars$mpg[1:2] <- c(50,60)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))
p + geom_boxplot()
```

Define max value:

```
maxval <- 40
```

Use `dplyr` (could also be done in base R or `plyr`) to extract outliers and put together the text string:

```
library("dplyr")
dd <- mtcars %>% filter(mpg>maxval) %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
        summarise(outlier_txt=paste(mpg,collapse=","))
```

Set max y value and add an arrow plus label:

```
library("grid") # needed for arrow() function
p2 <- p + geom_boxplot() +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(min(mtcars$mpg),maxval))+
       geom_text(data=dd,aes(y=maxval,label=outlier_txt),
                 size=3,vjust=1.5,hjust=-0.5)+
          geom_segment(data=dd,aes(y=maxval*0.95,yend=maxval,
                       xend=factor(cyl)),
                 arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1,"cm")))
p2
```

[image]